# Magento2 admin grid: SQL error when sorting by specific field

Tags: magento2, collection, uicomponent

Database table columns are displayed in custom grid in adminhtml. One of the field has name 'precision' and this causes SQL error when I sort the grid by this field (as this is mysql reserved word and must be used like this:

```
ORDER BY `precision` ASC
```

The question is: how to escape it or use an alias to avoid SQL error?

This field is defined in xml file like this:

```
    <column name="precision">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
            </item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="validate-digits-range" xsi:type="string">0-8</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Precision (0 - 8)</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple. In Collection.php:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init(MyClass::class, MyClassResourceModel::class);
    $this->_map['fields']['precision'] = 'main_table.`precision`';
    // any of these strings will do the same
    //$this->addFilterToMap('precision', 'main_table.`precision`');
    //$this->addFilterToMap('precision', 'main_table.precision');
    //$this->addFilterToMap('precision', '`precision`');
}
```

So if your field name is something like 'table' or 'count' you can do this trick to avoid SQL errors